# Mount folder linux (ubuntu) freezing when Windows 2012 Active Directory share change node (failover fileserver)

Tags: active-directory, share, mount

Windows 2012 file server (failover) ---> Ubuntu linux (not a member of Active Directory).

The mount works well, but when the file server changes node, the linux freezes (180 sec).

How to mount it so that the firewall is also turned on?

It works by turning off the firewall.